# Stop VSCode from typing " in pairs

Tags: scala, visual-studio-code

In VSCode (1.23.1) when I type a `"` it types it as `""` similarly when I am removing double quotes it tries to smartly find matching `"` and then removes it as well.

The problem with this behavior is that I use VSCode for scala where I have to write strings like `val s = """foo"""`. when typing this line VSCode fights with me tooth and nail because I need to type 3 quotes.

Is there a way to change this behavior?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46589115/disable-closing-bracket-swallowing/46965274#46965274  Unfortunately, the auto-matching-quote thing is tied to the   "editor.autoClosingBrackets": true, setting so setting that to false will solve your problem but you will lose the other (){} auto-insertion.  Maybe that is okay for you?

Comment: What version of VScode are you running? I'm running version 1.23.1 and I don't get this performance and I have "editor.autoClosingBrackets": true set.

Comment: You could limit the autoClosingBrackets : false setting to .scala files with a language-specific setting.  So it doesn't affect your other filetypes.

Comment: But like the above post said. I want this behavior only for `"`. I am OK with the behavior for `{` and `(`.